# Permisson in apk manifest Unity Android

Tags: android, unity3d, android-manifest

Есть плагины Facebook, OneSignal, Admob, Ads, Google play services, у некоторых есть свои манифесты, создается много разрешений, в самих манифестах их нет, как понял создаются при компиляции, как найти их и удалить? в пробовал извращаться архивами, при создании апк в папке StagingArea манифест просто объединился, а при загрузки апк в play market показывает в сведениях об апк что там значительно больше разрешений. Может там просто где то включается в манифесте true на набор разрешений?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам какие-то разрешения не нужны, и вы в этом уверены, то есть один хинт для этого: вы можете объявить этот же пермишн в своём основном манифесте, но указать ему низкий `maxSdkVersion`.

К примеру, если добавить такой пермишн:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:maxSdkVersion="1" />
```

И при этом минимальная версия sdk будет выше:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

Тогда этот пермишн не будет отображаться и запрашиваться никогда.